# Changing the page behind a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation's reveal modal to make an ajax request to open a sign up form in a modal. On submission of the form, an ajax call is being made to create a user using devise and I receive the new page as a response in my callback. How can I set the page behind the modal as the new response page, without closing the modal as there is one more step in the form left that is optional. Here is my function so far:

```
function submitAjax(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var user = {
    email: $('#user_email').val(),
    password: $('#user_password').val(),
    address: $('#user_address').val(),
    name: $('#user_name').val(),
    type: "homeowner"
  };
  var lawn_profile = {
    address: $('#lawn_profile_address').val(),
    description: $('#lawn_profile_description').val()
  };
  var params = {
    user: user,
    lawn_profile: lawn_profile
  };
  debugger;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/users",
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      document.write(response);
      debugger;
    }
  });
}
```

I have the debugger still in there from when I was trying to set the params that rails needs.

Comment: have you tried setting the dataType in the ajax call to HTML?

Comment: modal will be a child of body tag, just don't replace all body contents.Pretty hard for anyone to be more specific without some html layout given